# Pivot-type scenario with objects in C#

Tags: c#, database, search, object, pivot

Consider this scenario

I have a class called User which contains the a List of Car types (e.g Toyota, BMW)

So that is a User can have many cars.

Let's say I have a List of type User. In this current format, I can easily find all the Cars that a User owns.

What I cannot easily do, is find the all Users who own a particular Car type (e.g all Users who own a Toyota).

In the classical database sense I want to be able to pivot the data, but how does one achieve such an operation when working with objects like this in C#?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 4):

You have a one-to-many relationship so you can go both ways. Get cars that have users and get users who have cars. See the following C# code:

```
class Users
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var users = new List<Users>
                    {
                        new Users
                            {
                                Name = "Bob",
                                Cars = new List<Car> { new Car { Name = "Toyota" } }
                            }
                    };

// Any Cars with Name "Toyota" in a User's list of cars.    
var usersWithCar = users.Where(user => user.Cars.Any(car => car.Name == "Toyota"));


string userName = usersWithCar.Single().Name; // Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use Linq, first you'll need to add a reference to System.Linq (if it's not already done)

Next you can do something like this :

```
List<User> Example = new List<User>();
var Users_Having_A_Renault_ZE = Example.Where(
Me => Me.MyCars.Any(
    Car => Car.MyName == "Renault ZE"))
```

It means "Takes all users that have one ore more car named Renault ZE"
+ It supposed that MyCars is a List, an array or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to achieve this.

```
    class Car {}
    class Toyota : Car {}
    class BMW : Car {}

    class User
    {
        private readonly IList<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
        public IList<Car> Cars { get { return cars; } }
        public void AddCar(Car car)
        {
            Cars.Add(car);
        }
    }


    User user1 = new User();
    user1.AddCar(new BMW());
    user1.AddCar(new Toyota());

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.AddCar(new BMW());

    var users = new List<User>
                        {
                            user1,
                            user2
                        };
    IEnumberable<User> usersWithBMW = users.Where(u => u.Cars.Any(c => c is BMW));
```